# How to have two web parts side by side in same zone

Tags: web-part, web-part-zone

I have two web parts that i want to fit side by side in the same zone, however, I'm not sure how to go about this. I've modified the width of the individual web parts to be able to fit side by side but right now am only able to stack them on top of each other.

Any suggestions? I've seen on another question that you can add web parts in a table but I'm not sure how you do that either - when I create the table in one part i'm using the basic Rich Text Editor and don't seen an option to insert a web part.

Comment: I think we resolved this recently with a solution... Steve can you enlighten the folks here with some info on the webform parts (discussion forums / add files)? thanks. Oliver
Birmingham City University
01213317997

Answer (score 23):

Each webpart zone has a property called "Orientation"

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" AllowCustomization="true"   
AllowPersonalization="false" ID="MiddleTop" Title="Middle Top Zone" 
Orientation="Vertical"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

Change this to "Horizontal" and they will show side by side instead of vertically.

Here are so links to help you further:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ta/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/935a2bce-205a-4cda-9068-b64c355fbae9

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/insert-or-delete-a-web-part-zone-HA010151394.aspx

Comment: What worked for me was to also set LayoutOrientation="Horizontal" in addition to Orientation="Horizontal"

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem by adding a table with two column, then drag and drop the web part.
After that you can change the table style in Design Tab to "Clear".

Answer (score 2):

All that stuff your momma taught you about "never use HTML tables for page architecture"? Ignore it! SharePoint lives and breathes tables, right or wrong.

Shamelessly slap a two-column table on your page and cram a web part into either cell. Style the table cells as necessary to obtain the desired widths, and get over those feelings of shame and guilt that will follow.

Comment: Or listen to your momma and use spans (or inline divs) instead.

Answer (score 1):

When editing from the web interface, and you've selected "EDIT," on the "FORMAT TEXT" tab there's a "Text Layout" drop-down large icon. It's toward the right of the format text ribbon.

There are layout options that include "two columns."

[image: text layout]

Comment: This depends on if Mallory is using a wiki-style page, or generating content otherwise. You can create web part zones, that reside side-by-side alternatively to this.