# In a created web part zone can't re-arrange Web Part side by side

Tags: 2010, web

On a already created webzone I have two web parts, that are arranged one under the other. I want to arrange them side by side but I don't have admin permission or SharePoint Designer. how can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have two web parts side by side in same zone](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53967/how-to-have-two-web-parts-side-by-side-in-same-zone)

Comment: Sorry but the indicated post does not help at all

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to create a personal view of the web part page.  This gives you the ability to re-arrange the web parts the way you want and not affect other users.

On the top right hand side of your website, click the dropdown that has the name of the site in it. At the bottom of the selection you should see "Personalize this Page".

Here's an article with a bit more detail:
https://answers.uchicago.edu/page.php?id=25428

Comment: thank you very much for your link, unfortunately it doesn't help.  I have the web parts created, they are arranged in the webzone one under the other. All I want is to make them side by side.

Comment: Your tutorial presents a solution for a Personalized View. I don't want a personalized view. I want all the users to see the page the way I make midifications.