# WebPart Zone Wont change

Tags: web-part

I am using Design Manager (snippet) to add WebPart Zone which works fine, however this issue I have is all of the webparts are showing one after each other. How can I show them next to each other:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you wish webparts to appear side by side within WebPartZone then make sure that webparts you're adding have display attribute set to `inline` or `inline-block` or any other mechanism which ensures inline flow.

If you wish to have WebPartZones side by side then you have to design it in such a way, for example wrap them in `div` elements with display set to `inline-block`.

EDIT:

You can also set the `Orientation` attribute of the `WebPartZone` to `Horizontal`.

Source: [How to have two web parts side by side in same zone](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53967/how-to-have-two-web-parts-side-by-side-in-same-zone)

Comment: thanks Slaven, where would be those attributes, I have searched under Customisation - Web Part Zone and I cant find them. Please see the screen shot.

Comment: In the WebPartZone you can set Layout > LayoutOrientation > Horizontal as per your screenshot.