# Two Web Parts Side by Side

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx-webparts

I am having trouble customizing my SharePoint site. I want to add multiple webparts side by side on my page but SharePoint doesn't have this option natively. You can only add them in the downward direction not to the left or right. I already saw a similar question like this and it mentioned adding code using SharePoint Design.

I am very new to SharePoint and I don't understand how to add this specific code. I will link the question as it is very much similar to my ordeal.

This is the same question link: [How to have two web parts side by side in same zone](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53967/how-to-have-two-web-parts-side-by-side-in-same-zone)

I am using SharePoint Online.
And I know how to use spfx webparts. If there is a webpart that can accomplish this please link it.

Comment: Hi @Zahra, can you share more details, please? Are you using modern pages or classic pages? What kind of webparts are you trying to add side-by-side/

Comment: Hello, I am using SharePoint Modern pages. Trying to add images side by side. I already tried using 3 columns but the images are too big. I want at least 6 images in one row. I already tried using image gallery but I can't use it because I want the images when clicked on it redirects to a link. Can you please help me.

Comment: What I'm seeing is that a modern page allows max 3-column section where web-parts reside. That is, horizontally you can have 3 images. Of course you can use a custom web-part to handle your scenario.

Comment: Yes, I added this webpart to my SharePoint site: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-image-gallery but it doesn't work. I successfully added it to my site but when I add links it doesn't work. Do you know how I can customize my own webpart preferably with tutorials on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet in the post you mentioned seems to be used to modify the page layout (in classic pages), which I’m not sure if it can be used in modern pages since [customizing Master Page / Page Layouts are not supported](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages).

I would suggest you build additional columns in a web part section (also the second answer in the post) and then insert images within the cells.

Here is a related reference, see if it helps: [SPFx WebParts responsive to Modern Page sections.](https://ypcode.wordpress.com/2019/01/10/spfx-webparts-responsive-to-modern-page-sections/)